# Custom Django form validator doesnt render validation error on the frontend

Tags: python, django

I have a custom validator which should raise an error on the frontend for the user if the validation fails. However, I am not sure where and how to return this to the **frontend**. Right now it only shows in the terminal/Django error site on dev server:

**The view:**

```
def raise_poller(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':

        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = PollersForm(request.POST)

        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():

            # Make Validation of Choices Fields
            poller_choice_one = form.cleaned_data['poller_choice_one']
            poller_choice_two = form.cleaned_data['poller_choice_two']

            if ' ' in poller_choice_one or ' ' in poller_choice_two:
                raise ValidationError('Limit your choice to one word', code='invalid')

                return poller_choice_two  # !! IDE says this is unreachable

            else:

                # process the remaining data in form.cleaned_data as required

                poller_nature = form.cleaned_data['poller_nature']
                poller_text = form.cleaned_data['poller_text']
                poller_categories = form.cleaned_data['poller_categories']

                # Get the user
                created_by = request.user

                # Save the poller to the database
                p = Pollers(poller_nature=poller_nature,
                            poller_text=poller_text,
                            poller_choice_one=poller_choice_one,
                            poller_choice_two=poller_choice_two,
                            created_by=created_by)
                p.save()
                p.poller_categories.set(poller_categories)

                # redirect to a new URL:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = PollersForm()

    return render(request, 'pollinator/raise_poller.html', {'form': form})
```

**template**

```
{% block content %}

    <div class="poll-container">

        <form action="/raisepoller/" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
    
{% endblock %}
```

Also where to best structure/implement custom validators? After the `if form.is_valid` part?

Comment: Can you show how you render the form in the template?

Comment: Ah, but you need to do the validation in the `Form`, not in the view.

Comment: oh lol...that makes sense

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem so adding the validator into the form means `if form.is_valid` then considers my own validator within the form?

Comment: yes, like the answer of yedpodtrzitko. You implement this in the `clean` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show the error in the form, you have to raise the `ValidationError` in the form (instead of the view), because form expects and handles when `ValidationError` is eventually raised. [Read the docs about forms validation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)

```
class PollersForm(forms.Form):
  
    def clean(self):
       data = self.cleaned_data
       poller_choice_one = data['poller_choice_one']
       poller_choice_two = data['poller_choice_two']

       if ' ' in poller_choice_one or ' ' in poller_choice_two:
           # raising ValidationError here in clean does the trick
           raise ValidationError('Limit your choice to one word', code='invalid')
       return data
```

sidenote: if the only thing you are doing with the form is creating a model instance, you should consider using [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/) instead, which is designed exactly for this purpose. It will save you writing a lot of code.